# How to search a string for a specific character and return a number of occurrences?

Tags: r

I have a large data set which is essentially a frequency chart (linguistics). Two columns - `word` and `frequency`. What I need is to look for specific characters within the `word` column and return a number of occurrences in every row, so that I can create a new column with these values.

Example:

word: aardvark

/some unknown code: search `dataset$word` for character 'a', return 3. repeat for all 38k rows and create a new column `col.a`/

Comment: `nchar(gsub('[^a]', '', 'aardvark'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use str_count in stringr library:

```
library(stringr)

# example data
df <- data.frame(word = c("aardvark", "digest", "arc", "abandon"), 
             frequency = c(5, 6, 7, 4))

# count occurrence of letter a in every word             
df$a <- str_count(df$word, "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use also use `base R` to do this

```
df$a <- sapply(gregexpr("a", df$word),function(x) sum(x>0))
```